# UICollectionViewCell init method never call

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to override init method of `UICollectionViewCell` but it never get invocation.

I get the cell via `[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

so I tried `init, initWithFrame, initWithCoder` but it does not help me.

And were I can see for example in apple docs `UICollectionViewCell` lifecycle? Because I have not found it.

Comment: We use the default `initWithFrame:` in our code and it works just fine. Are you sure there isn't another issue here?

Comment: just recheck it I miss about changing register collection view cell with right class

Comment: Are you using prototype cells, a xib file or building the cell in code? How do you register the cell for reuse?

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question :) presumably you'd not specified the right class when registering?